# Insert a single background image for a TableView Cell Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm working on an app to gets data from a JSON an then put the results on a Table, but my problem is that i'm trying to set an image for each cell (same image) but after tried several ways i can't get the image right.

Here some of the code i've tried:

1.- In The background

```
  // Add a background view to the table view
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "bookshelf1.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    self.table.backgroundView = imageView
```

and in the cell:

```
      cell.textLabel?.text = wifiSpot["ssid"] as? String

       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

It shows like an expanded image of the image not the single image for each cell

2.- In the cell

```
      let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default,          reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        let wifiSpot : NSMutableDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary

        cell.textLabel?.text = wifiSpot["ssid"] as? String

       cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "bookshelf1.png")
```

But this way overlaps the text and also it shows a white column like if the image doesn't covers the whole cell

![Second Try]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHP6x.jpg

3.- Another way

```
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "bookshelf1.png")

        cell.textLabel?.text = wifiSpot["ssid"] as? String
```

It shows like this

![Third Try]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w22KH.jpg

I also tried to insert a ImageView on the prototype cell but only shows the image for the cell 1 .

Tried to ctrl drag from the Imageview on the prototype cell to a CustomTableViewCell an the create the cell like this :

```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

then call the image from the CustomTableViewCell like this:

```
       cell.postedImage.image = UIImage(named: "bookshelf1.png")
```

but it doesn't let me create the IBOulet .

Because my reputation it doesn`t let me to post more images

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it @Callam this is the code that i used and it worked like i wanted:

```
    var imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))

    let image = UIImage(named: "bookshelf1.png")

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    imageView = UIImageView(image:image)

    cell.backgroundView = imageView

  // An then the cell content

        cell.textLabel?.text = wifiSpot["ssid"] as? String

        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
```

Here is what i wanted to show:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpTJT.jpg

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the subview (`cell.imageView`) to the back of its superview (`cell`).

```
if let imageView = cell.imageView {
    cell.sendSubview(toBack: imageView)
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked @Callam still getting the same result http://imgur.com/9zu9ct7, or maybe i'm implement your suggestion in the wrong place.

Comment: No, i'm not using contraints , just the code i'm showing above